# difference in meaning - "Do you ever" vs "Do you"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

> Do you ever go to the movies?
>
> Do you go to the movies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the difference is one of degree. "Do you go to the movies?" is asking if you *habitually* or *regularly* go to the movies. If you say "no," then you might still go to the movies for a special occasion or to see a particularly enticing film. But you're not in the habit of going to the movies just because you have some time to spare.

On the other hand, "Do you ever go to the movies?" is more broadly asking if you go to the movies at all. If you say "no" to this, it means that you never go to the movies under any circumstances. You might have gone to the movies in the past, but not in the present or immediate future.

(If you want to ask about the past, you would have to phrase the sentence in the past tense, as "Did you ever go to the movies?" or "Have you ever gone to the movies?" which both mean approximately the same thing.)